Ubuntu 24.04 LTS update without nvidia-driver-470 and wireless Realtek RTL8811AU support
I am a long-time Ubuntu user. The last update from 23.10 to 24.04 LTS messed up my system. This concerns the support of nvidia-driver-470 and wireless Realtek RTL8811AU drivers. I would like to update the release, but I am afraid that my Ubuntu will crash again. Does anyone know if this has been fixed?

This answer doesn't solve my problem.
